# reCAPTCHA working on localhost but not on REMOTE server

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am having some issue adding the reCAPTCHA to my website. The code below works fine on my local host but not on my remote server.

```
    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {    
    $secret = '6LcUahkTAOlz-3iYApxHVjUC6wSc30G';
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    //var_dump($ip); works fine on both local and remote
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $rsp = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha&remoteip=$ip");
    var_dump($rsp);
    $validation = json_decode($rsp, TRUE);
    var_dump($validation);
    if ($validation['success'] !== true) {
        $errors[] = 'CAPTCHA failed. Please try again.';
        }
    }
```

var_dump($rsp)returns:

Local host:

```
string(91) "{ "success": false, "challenge_ts": "2016-02-27T17:08:05Z", "hostname": "localhost" }"
```

or

```
string(90) "{ "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2016-02-27T17:41:40Z", "hostname": "localhost" }"
```

Remote Server ALWAYS return:

```
bool(false)
```

var_dump($validation) returns:

Local Host:

```
array(3) { ["success"]=> bool(false) ["challenge_ts"]=> string(20) "2016-02-27T17:08:05Z" ["hostname"]=> string(9) "localhost" }
```

or

```
array(3) { ["success"]=> bool(true) ["challenge_ts"]=> string(20) "2016-02-27T17:41:40Z" ["hostname"]=> string(9) "localhost" }
```

Remote Server ALWAYS return:

```
NULL
```

I am NOT a programmer and have limited knowledge.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hand the problem to the programmer then, because posting secrets on the publicly available site isn't the smartest idea ever.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I modified it before posting, this is obviously not the real secret key. I don't have a programmer, I have created my website on my own with help. I just wanted to add the reCAPTCHA to my registration page as my database has been overloaded with robots.

Comment: Let me know if you have any idea why that same code is behaving differently between servers. Thanks!

Comment: did you properly register the domains and everything on recaptcha? You can't just generate two keys and then use them wherever you want, they have to be bound do the address of the website.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer: 
allow_url_fopen wasn't enabled on my remote host php file!
Thanks!

Comment: it worked for me too. that php directive was missing on my webhost. thanks!